# Spring MVC - Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.lang.Integer'

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, data-binding

Am new to Spring MVC. I have developed a sample application which performs SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE.

**Below is my Bean class**

```
@Id
@Column
private int student_id;
private String name;
private String age;
private String city;
private String country;
private Integer phone;
private int hsc;
private int sslc;
private int college;

/*getter and setters*/
```

**Below is my Controller Class**

```
@Controller
public class StudentController {

private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(StudentController.class);

@Autowired
private StudentService studentService;

@RequestMapping(value = "/students", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String listStudents(Model model){
    if(logger.isDebugEnabled()){
        logger.debug("listStudents method is executed!");
    }

    logger.error("This is an error message", new Exception("Testing"));
    model.addAttribute("student", new StudentDO());
    model.addAttribute("listStudents", this.studentService.listStudents());
    return "students";
}


@RequestMapping(value = "/students/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addStudent(@ModelAttribute("student") StudentDO studentDO){
    if(studentDO.getStudent_id() == 0){
        /**new person, add it*/
        this.studentService.addStudent(studentDO);
    }else{
        /**existing person, call update*/
        this.studentService.updateStudent(studentDO);
    }
    return "redirect:/students";
}
}
```

**Below is my JSP page**

```
<c:url var="addAction" value="/students/add" ></c:url>

<form:form action="${addAction}" commandName="student">

<table>

<c:if test="${!empty student.name}">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <form:label path="student_id">
                <spring:message text="STUDENT_ID"/>
            </form:label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <form:input path="student_id" readonly="true" size="8"  disabled="true" />
            <form:hidden path="student_id" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</c:if>

<tr>
    <td>
        <form:label path="name">
            <spring:message text="Name"/>
        </form:label>
    </td>
    <td>
        <form:input path="name" />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <form:label path="age">
            <spring:message text="Age"/>
        </form:label>
    </td>
    <td>
        <form:input path="age" />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <form:label path="city">
            <spring:message text="City"/>
        </form:label>
    </td>
    <td>
        <form:input path="city" />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <form:label path="country">
            <spring:message text="Country"/>
        </form:label>
    </td>
    <td>
        <form:input path="country" />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <form:label path="phone">
            <spring:message text="Phone"/>
        </form:label>
    </td>
    <td>
        <form:input path="phone" />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <form:label path="hsc">
            <spring:message text="HSC"/>
        </form:label>
    </td>
    <td>
        <form:input path="hsc" />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <form:label path="sslc">
            <spring:message text="SSLC"/>
        </form:label>
    </td>
    <td>
        <form:input path="sslc" />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <form:label path="college">
            <spring:message text="College"/>
        </form:label>
    </td>
    <td>
        <form:input path="college" />
    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td colspan="2">
        <c:if test="${!empty student.name}">
            <input type="submit" value="<spring:message text="Edit Student"/>" />
        </c:if>
        <c:if test="${empty student.name}">
            <input type="submit" value="<spring:message text="Add Student"/>" />
        </c:if>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Now am facing two issues.
1. After entering the values and clicked Add Student button, am getting the below error.

```
org.springframework.validation.BindException:     
org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 1 errors
Field error in object 'student' on field 'phone': rejected value [9962287970]; 
codes [typeMismatch.student.phone,typeMismatch.phone,typeMismatch.java.lang.Integer,typeMismatch]; 
arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [student.phone,phone]; arguments []; 
default message [phone]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.lang.Integer' for property 'phone'; 
nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "9962287970"]
```

2. By default values which I have declared as int are being displayed in my JSP by default as 0. When I changed the phone variable from int to Integer, 0 dint come. Why is it like this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that value 9962287970 is out of range for type `Integer`.

```
Integer.MAX_VALUE < 9962287970
```

To fix this change `private Integer phone;` to `private Long phone;` OR `private String phone;`

If you use `String` you can store other chars like `+` to the variable `phone`.

refer http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

The defauld value of `int` is 0 but for `Integer` it is not zero since it a object, so you have to initialize the value to 0;

Comment: yes u r correct. but how can i over come this? phone number will have 10 digits rite?

Comment: also consider changing phonenumber to String as a valid phone number can contain the characters "+" and ";". and they are not easy to store in Integer or long.

Answer (score 2):

You have exceeded the integer range so either use `Long` instead of `int` or make it of `String` variable type. After applying the changes don't forget to drop the table.

```
@Id
@Column
private int student_id;
private String name;
private String age;
private String city;
private String country;
private Long/String phone;
private int hsc;
private int sslc;
private int college;
```

Answer (score 1):

Issue 1. see this "nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "9962287970"". Since its beyond the range of int. try change it to String or Long.

Issue 2. In Java, int is a primitive type and it is not considered an object. Only objects can have a null value. As soon as the object of an class initialized all primitives set to their default value which is 0 in case of int.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

Answer (score 0):

Phone number isn't a number, it's a string of numbers.

e.g. 00159 222 111
and
0159 222 111

are different phone numbers but the same integer.

Comment: NB Your error is due to the phone number being out of range of int.
However underlying issue is phone numbers are not numbers as above.

Comment: This irrelevant to the question. User enter String and Bean class holds Integer

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue while testing, actually I am not passing any number from jsp input text(passing empty value - I removed javascript validation for easy testing) which cannot be converted to an integer. I know it is a silly mistake but thought it helps someone who is doing the same mistake.